# TYPO3 user rights - missing buttons “Select & upload files” and “Add media by URL”

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I have a problem with the user right management. In the resources tab the user is missing the buttons “Select & upload files” and “Add media by URL”.

any idea which option is missing?

[Backend as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUeid.png)

[Backend as user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7JVe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For drag'n'drop upload the editor needs to have access to the folder `user_upload`.

Answer (score 3):

Just enable "File upload directly in Doc-module" in user settings modules.

see screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answers from Pravin and Thomas are not completely correct (for my case in TYPO3 10). You have to do both configurations:

1. Allow access to fileadmin/user_upload for editor
2. The editor himself have to set in Settings > Edit and Advanced functions > File upload directly in Doc-module (or you use settings ins UserTS)